# How can I make OpenCV the default library for my qt projects?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5, qmake

Please suppose that I want to **link OpenCV libraries in Qt-creator**, in common, I will add headers using`INCLUDEPATH` and link libraries using the `LIBS` variable, which is used in the qmake file but if we use OpenCV in most of our projects then we have to include OpenCV library every time, so is there any way to add opencv libraries automatically at the time of creating a project.
I use the below command to add OpenCV libraries for my projects every time.

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres ...and etc.
```

---

**UPDATE**

I will use the following headers for OpenCV4:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You can create a .prf (project feature) file in your `mkspecs/features` directory:

> /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/opencv.prf

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres ...and another libraries
```

Now simply add `CONFIG += opencv` to your .pro file to have it working. Or you can even auto-enable this feature by editing `mkspecs/qconfig.pri`:

> /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri

```
...
CONFIG += ... opencv
...
```

BTW. `qconfig.pri` is a part of `qt_config`, which is loaded by all QMake's machine-dependent specs, so it should always work. However, it's also possible to patch only a specific spec (for example, `/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf`, or whatever is appropriate for your configuration). Of course, it's even possible to add all these `INCLUDEPATH+=...` and `LIBS+=...` straight into that `qmake.conf` and get rid of the .prf file completely.

2) Alternatively, if you don't want to pollute Qt installation, you can use manual include:

> opencv.pri

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres ...and another libraries
```

> myprogram.pro

```
include(path/to/opencv.pri)
...
```

Answer (score 4):

When you installed opencv you must also install the `opencv.pc` file, this file can be used to make it simple, since Qt supports package.config, if so, it replaces what it shows by the following:

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

Actually Qt Creator offers a simple way, you just have to right click on the name of your project and select the option Add Library:

[image]

Then you will get a dialog where you must select the type of library:

[image]

In this case I used the fourth option, and put the name of the library: opencv.

[image]

Then you press the next and finish buttons.

Comment: Thanks , I use pkg-config for that but I have to add this two lines to every .pro file?

Comment: @saeedmasoomi Yes, only those 2 lines, and not every opencv package.