# How to save incrementally images loaded on a QGraphicsView using QPushButton & OpenCV::imwrite

Tags: c++11, qt5, opencv3.0, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I prepared this small verifiable .ui in Figure 1 that replicates the issue I have:

[image: small example]

I am trying to use the `QPushButton` "Print Screen Both Images" to incrementally save images on Left and Right of the `QGraphicsView` into two different folders present on my Desktop, see below Figure 2:

[image: destination_folders]

I can take a print screen of either the `leftScene` or the `rightScene` by just clicking on their related `QPushButton` Print Screen Left and Print Screen Right.

However, I am trying for this specific case not to use `QFileDialog` as I need to silently and incrementally save the images in the two different destination folders as I move on with the right/left arrow.

See below the snipped of code I am using:

**mainwindow.h**

```
public:
    void bothPrintScreen(const std::string& pathImg);
private slots:
    void on_bothPrintScreen_clicked(const std::string& imgPath);
private:
    int counterA=0;
    int counterB=0;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_bothPrintScreen_clicked(const std::string& imgPath)
{
    bothPrintScreen(imgPath);
}

void MainWindow::bothPrintScreen(const std::string& pathImg){
    cv::Mat left, right;
    std::string outA = pathImg+"/printScreenA_"+std::to_string(counterA++)+".png";
    cv::imwrite(outA,left);
    std::string outB = pathImg+"/printScreenB_"+std::to_string(counterB++)+".png";
    cv::imwrite(outB,right);
}
```

I am missing something in the code but I am not sure what exactly.

The compiler is seinding this `allocate()/deallocate()` error that I don't understand:

[image: compiler_error]

Please shed light on this matter.

Comment: It's linker errors. Add opencv to the LIBS in your qt project file or in CMake.

Comment: Hi Nuzhny, thanks for the comment. Could you please put a couple of lines of code so that I can mark your answer as correct? :)

Comment: I mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611221/add-opencv-library-to-every-qt-project

Comment: Yes exactly, if you can add here that lines of code I will mark your answer as correct because the compiler is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need to add OpenCV libraries to the your Qt project ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611221/add-opencv-library-to-every-qt-project))

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres ...and another libraries
```